# PublicKey.Key.Encrypt error You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

I keep getting the null-valued error on this script:

```
$key = $cert.PrivateKey.Decrypt($object.Key, $true)
```

It's taken from the powershell examples so I have no idea why it's not working.  Any clue?  The certificate is found correctly by using it's thumb-print, and the secret key is in it.

This is running on Windows 2012 R2 with powershell v4

```
try
{
    $object = Import-Clixml -Path c:\temp\encryptionTest.xml

    $thumbprint = '58E3080C84336ECFBBF9EFFCFF98788880F0BA5F'

    $cert = Get-Item -Path Cert:\LocalMachine\My\$thumbprint -ErrorAction Stop

    $key = $cert.PrivateKey.Decrypt($object.Key, $true)
    $cert.PrivateKey
    $secureString = $object.Payload | ConvertTo-SecureString -Key $key
    $secureString
}
finally
{
    if ($null -ne $key) { [array]::Clear($key, 0, $key.Length) }
}
```

UPDATE:  I contacted the script author and he mentionned that the problem is that .NET does not play nicely out of the box with CNG (Crypto Next Generation)certificates which are identified as version 3(which is exactly the version we use)  He supplied a new function that work with those.

Comment: I should add that the file c:\temp\encryptionTest.xml includes the text I am trying to decrypt and that file was previously created using the encrypt version of the script and that one is working correctly

Comment: You do get something if you just print/run `$cert.PrivateKey` at that point in the script?

Comment: Hmm, indeed, $cert.PrivateKey appear empty

$cert contains the certificate itself correctly.

Why would that be?

Comment: Other than that not being the cert you expect I'm not sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted the script author and he mentionned that the problem is that .NET does not play nicely out of the box with CNG (Crypto Next Generation)certificates which are identified as version 3(which is exactly the version we use) He supplied a new function that work with those.

https://github.com/dlwyatt/ProtectedData

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue but instead of picking up the cert from Cert:\LocalMachine\My, I changed it to

```
$cert = Get-Item -Path Cert:\CurrentUser\My\$thumbprint -ErrorAction Stop
```

and it works fine.